# JavaScript, var a=5; vs b=5;

Tags: javascript, dom, scope, global-variables, local

See this code:

```
    var a=5; //Scope: Global
    b=5;     //Scope: Global
```

> What's the difference in a and b? Both belong to the Global scope and hence below to the window object of Document Object Model.

Then what's the difference in a and b?
I am new to JavaScript so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you are using it in global space then no difference, but you're using this inside a block then `var a = 5` will be local and `b = 5` will be global.

Comment: Small rule: always declare variables!